# Chern class and multiplication structure

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles

Let $c_i$ be the i-th  Chern class of vector bundle $F→E→B$.
By Leray-Hirsch formula ,we have $H^*(PE)$ isomorphic to $H^*(B)  \bigotimes\mathbb{Z}｛x^1,…,x^{n-1}｝$ as $H^*(B)-module$. Where $PE$ is the projectivization of $E$. $x$ is the generator of $H^*(PF)$.

The question is if $c_i=0$ for all $i$,do we have $H^*(PE)$ isomorphic to $H^*(B)  \bigotimes\mathbb{Z}｛x^1,…,x^{n-1}｝$ as rings?

Comment: Strictly speaking $H^*(B) \otimes \mathbb{Z}\{x, \ldots, x^{n-1}\}$ doesn't imply a (full) ring structure on its own.  However, what you can deduce from the vanishing of Chern classes is that $x^n = 0$.